# Enumerate indentation without items

Tags: lists, enumerate, description

In my document I have a number of questions, some with enumerable items and others with no items. I would like the body of each question to have similar margins regardless of contents.

My current workaround is to place the text of questions without enumerable items into descriptions without items. Latex will compile this, but produces an error. How can I easily achieve the same formatting without causing an error?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,xfrac}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{1}\hfill
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    $\text{average traffic per user} = 100kbps \times 0.1 = 10kbps$ \\
    $\text{peak traffic per user} = 100kbps$
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}\hfill
  \begin{description}
  $P_n=(1-\rho)\rho^n$ \\
  $\rho = \sfrac{5.4}{6.0} = 0.9$ \\
  $B = 50, N > B \longrightarrow N >= B + 1$ \\
  $P_N = 1 - \sum_{b}^{B+1}P_{b} = 0.004638397686588025 \approx 0.464\%$ \\
  The packet loss probability due to buffer overflow is $0.464\%$. \\
  \end{description}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

error

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 32 ended by \end{trivlist}.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36 \end{question}

--- HELP ---
No help available
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example which reproduces your error

Comment: your code is not compileable

Comment: It compiles for me, I'll add the error I get.

Comment: It only compiles for you because you have embedded it in a complete document, which starts with `\documentclass`, loads some packages, has `\begin{document}` and so on. We do not have any information about the document class you are using, nor on the packages, nor on the output you want to reproduce, so it is hard if not impossible to answer your question.

Comment: The PDF won't be produced if there's an error... A `description` environment is a list, and a list needs an `\item`. Yours doesn't, hence the error. Also, what indentation are you referring to with a `description` that doesn't have any `\item`s?

Comment: The items in an enumerated block are indented uniformly. I want to match this indentation with the text in other blocks which do not have items.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about the pdf, it is being output and it has the formatting I like. I assume there is something obvious I should be doing instead, but this works for now.

Comment: The obvious issue with your code is that you start an `enumerate` without closing it; that is, you have `\begin{enumerate}` with an `\item` but no `\end{enumerate}` within the first `question` environment.

Answer (score 3):

You provided no usable example so I can't show the output, but in all list environments that use `\item` you can use the optional argument to specify a different label and so `\item[]` to specify no label at all. In fact this is how most latex displays environment such as `center`, `quote` etc are defined, as a one-item list with no no label.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not sure what I could post besides the entire document itself, as I don't know what it is necessary.

Comment: @Paul you should post a complete but small document. between begin document and end document it just needs the `question` environment you posted, but you should add `\documentclass{article}` and any packages and definitions required to run it, for example `question ` has no definition by default. A code block that no one can run to see the problem or test answers really does not help clarify the question at all.

Comment: I have updated my post with a minimal document showing what is going on.